# Conditionnal Loop over a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a beginner in Python and I usually program in C.

So, I have a numpy 2D array. I do the mean of the (i,j),(i+1,j),(i,j+1) and (i+1,j+1) values and I sum this mean if it is above a chosen value.

This is my python code :

```
Z=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])
sum=0.
value=7.
for i in range(np.shape(Z)[0]-1):
    for j in range(np.shape(Z)[1]-1):
        a = (Z[i,j] + Z[i+1,j] + Z[i,j+1] + Z[i+1,j+1]) / 4
        if (a>=value):
            sum+=a
print (sum)
```

I know It does not sound very pythonic. How can I write it in pythonic way to speed up this code on a large 2D numpy array ?

Thanks for answer

Comment: Making your code "pythonic" won't speed it up, it's just about coding style.

Comment: @GG. If you take cache hit/miss rate into consideration, it will probably have a huge impact since numpy organizes its arrays in consecutive chunks.

Comment: @GG. It speeds up. Look at my comment in the answer.

Comment: It speeds up because he optimized your algorithm.

Comment: @GG. I think it is possible easily in python and "pythonic" code. Is it possible to optimize my code with for loops ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
quads = Z[:-1,:-1] + Z[1:,:-1] + Z[:-1,1:] + Z[1:,1:]
sum = quads[quads >= value * 4].sum() / 4
```

The first line computes the entire (x-1,y-1) array of sums of 2x2 elements:

```
array([[16, 20, 24, 28],
       [36, 40, 44, 48]])
```

The second line compares each of those 8 elements with `value * 4`, rather than dividing `quads / 4` which would create another array of the same size unnecessarily.  This lets us do a single scalar multiply and a scalar divide at the end, instead of an array divide.  But you could also write it this way if you don't care about the optimization:

```
quads /= 4
sum = quads[quads >= value].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is much faster. I tested it on a 1000*1000 array with %timeit in jupyter notebook. My question  : 2.19 seconds, your answer : 13.5 **milli** seconds.